# Sorting a list of tuples without using lambda

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, tuples

I am yet to learn the 'lambda' concept in python, I tried to look for answers and every answer includes lambda in it. This is my code, can you please suggest me a way to sort it by values.

```html
sorted_dict = {'sir': '113', 'to': '146', 'my': '9', 'jesus': '4', 'saving': '275', 'changing': '72', 'apologize': '285', 'pain': '308', 'sisters': '27', 'forgiving': '36', 'can': '62', 'family': '77', 'sorry': '8', 'is': '360', 'too': '15', 'her': '37', 'wanted': '18', 'being': '44', 'into': '208', 'are': '17', 'just': '97', 'so': '148', 'now': '112', 'be': '19', 'right': '189', 'been': '105', 'no': '56', 'because': '74', 'forgive': '52', 'keep': '88', 'wish': '12', "i'm": '67', 'always': '53', 'ask': '29'}

new_list = list()
for key,value in sorted_dict.items():
    new_tup = (key, value)
    new_list.append(new_tup)

new_list = sorted(new_list)
```

How do i proceed further?

Comment: You can just use a regular function definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lambda is often used as the key to sort every value in an iterator.

The same step from turning dictionaries to list of tuples, can be done using the dict method `dict.items()`.

and i used lambda in sorting, as a key to tell the sorted function that, i want to sort based on the value in each tuple located in the 1st index.

```
sorted_dict = {'sir': '113', 'to': '146', 'my': '9', 'jesus': '4', 'saving': '275', 'changing': '72', 'apologize': '285', 'pain': '308', 'sisters': '27', 'forgiving': '36', 'can': '62', 'family': '77', 'sorry': '8', 'is': '360', 'too': '15', 'her': '37', 'wanted': '18', 'being': '44', 'into': '208', 'are': '17', 'just': '97', 'so': '148', 'now': '112', 'be': '19', 'right': '189', 'been': '105', 'no': '56', 'because': '74', 'forgive': '52', 'keep': '88', 'wish': '12', "i'm": '67', 'always': '53', 'ask': '29'}

new_list = sorted_dict.items()

new_list = sorted(new_list, key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
print(new_list)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly fine. But whyis the other answer not working in the same way? what is the difference when we create a function and then use it from using a lambda?

Comment: lambda is often used when dealing with one liner functions, or for the ease of use. it is a pain defining a function for a small task, especially if it's performed only once, it just hogs memory for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

if you are familiar with other programming concepts, you may have heard of what is called an "inline function"...

Lambda is an "inline function" equivalent in Python..

its a function which doesnt have a function name, and is restricted to have only a single line of code.

now coming to the problem of sort, the sort function in python accepts two arguments,

1. the list to be sorted
2. a function where you can define how to sort a list.

Suppose if its a list of numbers , you dont need the 2nd argument at all..

But if its like your case, where its a list of tuples or say a list of dictionaries,you need to tell python how to sort that list..

That is accomplished with the help of the '`key`' argument in the sort function...

Below code is an illustration of that..

```
In [1]: l1 = [('a',1), ('b', 3), ('c', 2)]

In [2]: def sortHelper(x):
   ...:     return x[1]
   ...:

In [3]: l1.sort(key=sortHelper)

In [4]: l1
Out[4]: [('a', 1), ('c', 2), ('b', 3)]

In [5]:
```

Now as you see, the `sortHelper` method is just a single line function, which can very well be written with a `lambda` function.

```
lambda x: x[1]
```

So its common to use lambda functions, but its not a compulsion.. you can accomplish the same functionality with normal python functions also..

Comment: I tried this, but the problem is not solved. I need the numbers to be sorted in ascending or descending but it is not the case here.